# Explain this: I use an application that runs faster in XP Mode than it does when run from the host Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, performance, windows-xp-mode

The application was developed (elsewhere) in Visual FoxPro 7 and 9.  It runs locally, but accesses data on the server for some operations; when it does this, there are huge delays if the application is running in Windows 7, but not if it's running in XP Mode on the same machine.  Any ideas?  The developers are stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible for many reasons.

Firstly, on XP you have less traffic-intensive services running, for example you have IPv4 on XP, while IPv4/6 on Windows 7. Another may be Homegroup polling on Windows 7.

The likely reason, though, is better driver support for your NIC on XP.

Or this could rather be too much support in the Windows 7 driver. I would check the Windows 7 NIC and maybe try to disable "Large Send Offload" and/or "Checksum Offloading", if they apply.

You could also disable ipv6 in Windows 7 if you don't need it.

Comment: All good suggestions.  I've tried most of them: the host is not running IPv6, Homegroup is disabled, and the NIC is configured to disable all offloading.  I've checked for newer NIC drivers and found nothing.  It does look like a networking issue, though.  It's just odd that the host is so much slower, but then again I suppose the guest is basically bypassing networking on the host.  So it's not as weird as if hard drive access was faster in the guest.

Comment: I hope you looked for a driver on the website of the NIC's manufacturer. If this NIC's performance is better in Vista, you could "downgrade" to that driver in Windows 7. The last resort is to try another NIC, maybe better-supported under Win7.

Comment: See also [Windows 7 Network Slow – 6 Easy Ways to Make it Fast](http://www.sysprobs.com/windows-7-network-slow).

Comment: @harrymc: (red-faced) I think I checked the the NIC manufacturer's site, but I will do so again to be sure. Thanks for the reminder. As for the 6 Easy Ways, I've done 1, 3, 5 and 6 with no luck and will try the others.  And again, thanks!

Comment: @harrymc: There was a newer drive from RealTek; I tried it and it made no difference.  I noticed that installing a new driver resets all the NIC settings to their default, so changed those again. Tried all the other suggestions in that article; no luck. I'm starting to think it's a FoxPro issue or just something being done dumbly (is that a word?) in the code. Now, if I had access to the source code...

Comment: I believe that you have done all that is humanly possible with this NIC. If it is only FoxPro, then maybe there is a difference regarding 32/64 bits ?

Comment: @harrymc: The PC hardware, Windows 7 and the application are all 32-bit. But that was a good idea, though.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as the original problem appears to be mostly a fault in the application.  There's also lots of good stuff here for dealing with Windows 7 network issues.

Comment: Followup: we reverted the machines in question to Windows XP and everything runs fine.